# Import Namespace in ascx don't work

Tags: asp.net, import, localization, ascx

```
<%@ Import namespace="Project.Web.Localization" %>
<%:Shared.LogOnUserControl.Account%>
```

I try this to make shorter my code :),
but it didn't work :(

ASP didn't find folder Shared.

but this is working `<%:Project.Web.Localization.Shared.LogOnUserControl.Account%>`

Comment: this isn't real question ! What are you asking for ?

Comment: `<%@ Import namespace="Project.Web.Localization" %>
<%:Shared.LogOnUserControl.Account%>` this i write, but have error something like "Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Shared' does not exist in the current context". It's only work like this `<%:Project.Web.Localization.Shared.LogOnUserControl.Account%>`. Maybe there is another way to import namespace or i miss something. thanks ( i want to get information from resources)

Comment: this is a syntax why you wanna break it ?

Comment: @AliUmair i want to import namespace to make shorter my code lines. that's all. but in my case, i can't do it and i don't know reason of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand, i can import only namespace to ended file in the path: 
`<%@ Import namespace="Project.Web.Localization.Shared" %>` and now i can use like this `<%:LogOnUserControl.Account%>` So now i am try to refactor my code to much general

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592248/whats-the-meaning-of-this-syntax-in-visual-studio) and [this](http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-%283c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc%29.aspx) .

This is complete namespace `Project.Web.Localization.Shared.LogOnUserControl.Account`

This can be a namespcae `Project.Web.Localization` but this ain't `Shared.LogOnUserControl.Account` . You are trying to break the property of `Import` called `namespace` which is illegal syntax . Or you can use `web.config` like described [here](http://hugoware.net/blog/making-usercontrols-and-namespaces-work)