# Whats the meaning of this syntax in Visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Does anyone know the meaning of the following 4 code snipets (or shortcuts, i don't know how to call them) in Visual Studio:

```
<%= variable %>
<%# variable %>
<%: variable %>
<%$ variable %>
```

I know the first one inserts a value into the page and the second one is used for data binding.

Are there any other similar shortcuts?

Comment: This question looks like [ASP.NET "special" tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags).

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, you are right! Since i didn't think of the word 'tags' and searching with the actual tags didn't return any results I thought I'd post a new question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one, `<%= %>` is called an inline expression, or a code render block. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xeyd4z(v=vs.100).aspx)

The second one, `<%# %>` is called a data binding expression. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx(v=vs.100).aspx)

The third one, `<%: %>` provides a way to automatically HTML encode the output of the code. I'm not sure what's it's called though so can't find you a documentation page on it, however there is a post on Scott Guthrie's blog: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx

The fourth one, `<%$ %>` is called expression builder syntax. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad(v=vs.100).aspx)