# Why my asp:Literal control doesn't work in a asp:ListView ItemTemplate

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms

Why my asp:Literal control doesn't work in a asp:ListView ItemTemplate ?
ASP.NET 4.5 WebForms

ASPX code  :

```
 <asp:ListView ID="lv" runat="server" ItemType="WebApplication1.ItemClass">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%#: Item.HtmlText %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
```

ASPX code behind :

```
    this.lv.DataSource = new ItemClass[] {
                    new ItemClass() { HtmlText = "<p>Hello 01<br/>blablabla</p>"},
                    new ItemClass() { HtmlText = "<p>Hello 02<br/>blablabla</p>"},
                    new ItemClass() { HtmlText = "<p>Hello 03<br/>blablabla</p>"}
};

                this.lv.DataBind();
```

My object class :

```
public class ItemClass
{
    public string HtmlText { get; set; }
}
```

Result on my page :

```
<p>Hello 01<br/>blablabla</p> <p>Hello 02<br/>blablabla</p> <p>Hello 03<br/>blablabla</p>
```

I can see html elements tags. I don't known why.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the colon character (:) in your code block, it automatically HTML encodes the output. (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592248/whats-the-meaning-of-this-syntax-in-visual-studio/17592716#17592716) for more information)

To fix this, simply drop the colon from your code, so it looks like this instead:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lv" runat="server" ItemType="WebApplication1.ItemClass">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%# Item.HtmlText %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```